# ProfileReport(df) shows calculated intervals as MISSING, REJECTED, UNSUPPORTED

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, date-arithmetic

Within a dataframe, I converted strings in m/d/yyyy format to datetimes and then subtracted them to get intervals. For some reason these calculated fields are described as MISSING, REJECTED, UNSUPPORTED in pandas.ProfileReport() and I am unable to use them in the .agg calculations

```
df['RequestedStartDT']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Requested Start Date'])
df['RequestedEndDT']    = pd.to_datetime(df['Requested End Date'])

df['TargetedStartDT']   = pd.to_datetime(df['Targeted Start Date'])
df['TargetedEndDT']     = pd.to_datetime(df['Targeted End Date'])

df['ActualStartDT']     = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual Start Date'])
df['ActualEndDT']       = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual End Date'])

df['RequestedInterval']       = df['RequestedEndDT']    - df['RequestedStartDT']
df['TargetedInterval']        = df['TargetedStartDT']   - df['TargetedEndDT']
df['ActualInterval']          = df['ActualEndDT']       - df['ActualStartDT']
```

Any suggestions for a better way to calculate and aggregate these intervals?

Here's a sample of the data
[image]

Comment: Hi jch, can you add some sample data to this question along with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TUrns out I need to explicitly convert the fields

```
df['RequestedInterval']       =df['RequestedInterval']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')
df['TargetedInterval']        =df['TargetedInterval']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')
df['ActualInterval']          =df['ActualInterval']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')
```